# Getting path of exe files from hard drive VB net

Tags: vb.net

Looking for a way that I can get the path of all exe files on an already specified drive. Or, get the path of a specified program.

Eg: specified c drive, program is excel. Code should then find the path for excel.

Or 
Eg: gets path of all exe files, puts them in an array, can then search the array for the program that needs to be fetched.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help
Ash

Comment: Could you share the code you wrote so far?

Comment: I don't think retrieving all exe files' path is a efficient way, cause there are too many exe files in the computer.
Or do you want to search only in the C:\Program Files directory?

Comment: Yeah, exe's from the program files directory

Answer (score 0):

this code returns all exe files full paths from c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office directory into szFiles array then fetch for excel...

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim szFiles() As String, i As UInteger
    szFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For i = 0 To szFiles.Length - 1
        If InStr(szFiles(i), "EXCEL", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then MessageBox.Show("Result found for Excel..." & szFiles(i))
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Hope it helps.